# Выборка товаров по вложенным категориям

Tags: sql

Необходимо провести выборку по вложенным категориям

```
catalog
-adidas
--shoes
---sneakers
-nike
--shoes
---sneakers
....
```

если передаю в get параметре catalog нужно вывести все вложенные товары, если shoes все его вложенные товары и тд.

```
SELECT p.name, p.category_id FROM `products` as p
where p.category_id in (select c.id from `category` as c where c.alias = 'catalog') 
or p.category_id in (
    select c.id 
    from `category` as c 
        where c.parent_id = (
            select c.id 
            from `category` as c 
                where c.alias = 'catalog'
        )
)
```

этот код работает, но мне код не нравится. можно ли его улучшить?

Comment: *этот код работает* - только в частных случаях. *мне код не нравится* - и правильно. *можно ли его улучшить?* - нет. Только выбросить и написать заново. Используя рекурсивный CTE.

Comment: попытался понять как реализовать рекурсивный CTE для моего случая, но ничего не понял. попробую еще. спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Добавил ответ снизу. работает отлично. спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 1):

Теперь я доволен и кодом и выводом.

```
with recursive cte (id) as (
  select id 
  from category 
        where alias = 'catalog'
    
  union all
    
  select c.id 
    from category as c 
    inner join cte 
        on c.parent_id = cte.id
)
select * from products where category_id in (select * from cte);
```

Благодарю @Akina